# File does NOT exist but ls shows "No such file or directory" error

Tags: linux, bash, ls

```
File system ext4 //
which ls -> /bin/ls //
Bash -> 3.2.57(2)-release //
whoami -> admin
```

If I run `ls` then I firstly get a list of files with error

> "No such file or directory"

and then the healthy files of the directory.

The folder that contains these bad files has an unusual size:

[image]
[image]

Concerning the files with error, I cannot:

1. delete the file
2. copy the file
3. move the file
4. delete the directory since it is not empty (`rm -r [DirectoryName]`)
5. Bad files are not shown/listed on either Mac OS nor MS-Windows

I can:

1. Move the content of the directory (`mv`) including bad files
2. Get tab to complete the name of the bad file

Any hint? Either to delete them or to recover them.

Comment: which distro are we talking about?

Comment: cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.12.6 (root@NasX86-12) (gcc version 4.1.3 20070929 (prerelease) (Ubuntu 4.1.2-16ubuntu2))

Comment: Have you tried unmounting and fsck'ing the filesystem ?

Comment: The system runs badblock from the user menu (not e2fsck). Running badblock does not make any difference; I do still have same problem. I will try e2fsck -in two weeks, and see.

Comment: @davidgo: that was the solution to my problem! That is to run e2fsck. Can you please create the according answer so I can score it?

Comment: For the record: I relied on QNAP "scan now" feature to take care of the integrity of the volumes in all senses. Unfortunately "scan now" only executes command `badblocks` which does not cover problems with i-nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment - the solution was to unmount and fsck the filesystem (using e2fsck or fsck.ext4).

It would seem that the filesystem got corrupted - possibly due to a sudden outage while writing to the disk - and the filesystem would have detected the problem and locked itself until repaired to prevent further damage to itself.